# How to import a package from a different location?

Tags: java, import

[image]

I'm trying to import the package model into CVue.java, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the package with keyword: Import "name_of_the_package".*;

i.e   import UI.*

In this way you will import every classs inside that package